# Animation with hasFocus()

Tags: java, android, animation, android-edittext

Im trying to animate my EditText to expand on focus. I can do it when it is onClick method but I want it to be when it has Focus. The code I'm trying to use is

```
if(mSearchBar.hasFocus()){
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(WebActivity.this,R.anim.searchbar_scale);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        mSearchBar.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

but It does not animate. I was wondering if you could help me out with the predicament that I've hit. It seems simple but I'm novice when it comes to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnFocusChangeListener`.

```
mSearchBar.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, focus) -> {
    if (!focus)
        return;
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(WebActivity.this,R.anim.searchbar_scale);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(anim);
});
```